# IE8 not allowing jQuery to give focus to textbox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, focus

I have jQuery which produces a popup window, as outlined here:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/sLjfx/4/

The problem is that the following line:

```
$('#txtValuation').focus();
```

doesn't seem to want to work in IE8. The popup will load, but the textbox doesn't have focus, where in Chrome the box does have focus.. Is there any work-around for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<s>I don't have IE8 handy, but try this:</s> I fired up my Windows VM, and this works: http://www.jsfiddle.net/n25HE/ All I did was wrap the `focus` call in a function and call it 10ms after your event handler finished, like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#txtValuation').focus();
}, 10);
```

This gives IE time to actually render the content and create the OS control for the text input. IE can't focus things before the underlying control exists.

Comment: This is still a problem in IE9. Since you will probably run into it more than once in an app, you can refactor it out in a function to stay DRY as explained here:
http://zadasnotes.blogspot.com/2011/01/let-ie-breath.html